# Java If Statement with && and .equal

Tags: java

I have the following:

```
Team A:
#   Name
0-1 Tim
2-3 Ryan
3-4 Jim

Team B:
#   Name
0-1 John
2-3 Joan
3-4 Todd
```

I would like to write an if statement when I only have the # value and the team.  So if I knew someone had a value of 1 and was on Team A, I would want it to show "Tim." This is what I have come up with so far but I am not having any luck.  Any suggestions?

```
if(#>=0 & Team.equal("Team A")) {
  'Tim'
 } else if(#<=1 & Team.equal("Team A")) {
   'Tim'
 } else if(#>=2 & Team.equal("Team A")) {
   'Ryan'
 } else if(#<=3 & Team.equal("Team A")) {
   'Ryan'
 } // etc.. until all the people are listed in the conditions.
```

Comment: Split the code into multiple lines please?

Comment: Every number appears to be `>= 0` so that's not a great first test. Also, real code please... obviously your pseudo code here isn't legal. How do you have the above scores?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? In your code there are two cases for #3 Team A and #3 Team B. why not number them 0-2, or 1-3, instead of the weird two number sytem

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. It is not 0-1 because they can have the value of 0 or 1 and be on Team A if that makes sense.  I am trying to say if someone is on team A and has the value of either 1 or 0 then display the name of Tim.

Comment: You probably want to change the `&` to `&&`.

Comment: @barakmanos True, and it should probably be `equals` instead of `equal`. That being said, it looks more like pseudocode that the OP plans on turning into java later.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [SmartParam](http://smartparam.org/) project. It allows you to define all conditions in plain file and evaluate using its engine. You can find similar solution in [this tutorial](https://github.com/smartparam/smartparam-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/smartparam/examples/simple/range/SimpleParameterWithRangeMatcherExample.java)

Comment: Well now that is really swatting flies with a sledgehammer.

Comment: Live shows that number of that parameters will grow. So you can choose if you prefer additional dependency or dozens if statements

Answer (score 1):

Do blocked checks.
Check team, then >0, then specifics.

```
if(team.equals("Team A"){
    if(num>=0){
        if(num <2)
           return "Tim";
        else if(num<4)
           return "Ryan";
         ...etc
    }
}
else if(team.equals("Team B"){
   ... etc
}
```

Comment: A `switch` statement for each team might be clearer.

Comment: It would, but nesting switches inside conditionals is ugly

Comment: You could pull them out into separate methods for each team. Just a thought.